# Encoding error while trying to read Hindi text from csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, hindi

I am trying to read Devanagari Text from a csv file using pandas. I am getting an error when using `encoding="utf-8"`. When i changed `encoding="latin1"`, I am getting NaN values.

Please help if someone has already encountered a similar problem or knows how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the Error I am getting:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position
>   31: invalid start byte

Comment: You can open the file in a text editor like Notepad++ and look at the encoding. It may be something else, for example UCS2. Or use this online [tool](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/)

Comment: you need to figure out the encoding of your input file. if its hindi it can't be latin1 which doesn't support those characters, and seems like its not utf-8. for starters I would try utf-16 or utf-32

Comment: Let's see the file, or part of it.